# Is it possible to move Windows 11 Storage Spaces to Windows Server 2022 Storage Pools?

Tags: storage-spaces, storage-pool, windows-server-2022

I created a Storage Pool (Mirror) on Windows 11 with two Drives (Mirror).  Then, My System crashed.  So, I took out the Drives and added them to my Windows Server 2022.  However, I am not seeing the Storage pools on Windows Server 2022.  The two Drives show-up in Disk Management on the Server and also show-up under Server Manager / File and Storage Services / Volumes / Disks.

[image: Disk Management View of the "RAID" Drives.]

There are no storage Pools listed on Windows Server. Windows Server 2022 Storage Pool UI.

### [image: Windows Server 2022 Storage Pool UI]

[image]

If I use PowerShell, Get-Disk displays the Disks on the List of disks.  Disk 0 and Disk 1 are the two Drives that are part the Mirrored Storage Pool from Windows 11.

[image: Disk 0 and Disk 1 are the two Drives that are part the Mirror]

PowerShell's Get-StoragePool only displays the C drive. The other Drives do not show-up.

[image: Get-StoragePool description]

Is it possible for me to revive the StoragePool from Windows 11 on my Windows Server 2022?

Comment: What type of storage was it (simple, mirror, parity)?

Comment: It is a Mirror StoragePool from Windows 11.

Comment: Windows Server 2022 should have recognized the Storage Pool. (1) Are you sure the disks are not damaged? (2) Do you see the files on each disk separately with Explorer? (3) Do you have backups of the data? (4) Try in PowerShell run as Admin the command `Repair-SpacesConfiguration`.